# User Session value on fieldset input

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I have a code below the submit action, however before this screen, i have a login screen. So with the current 
 i want to add to the "thisuser" input value below form. Current value is "TEST+USER"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1">

<title>untitled document</title>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen">-->

<style media="screen">
fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
 }
input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
 }
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7em;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body> 

 <form action="http://trackit/app-copy/curl_create.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>
   <input type="hidden" name="thisuser" value="TEST+USER">
    <label for="summ">Summary:</label>
     <input type="text" id="summ" name="summ"><br>
    <label for="comment">Description:</label>
     <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?I haven't understood a word whats....

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="thisuser" value="<?php echo $_POST['user']; ?>">
```

Note: It's highly recommended to filter and validate your data to pass it in your code. You may use `<?php echo (int)$_POST['user']; ?>` to be sure the value is always integer at least.

Note 2: Use **POST** method instead of **GET** for your forms.